# How can I know which are my rights

Tags: process, kill, user-permissions

On a fedora server, I have access to the cli. On that server I have a webapp which generates some pdf files using a php library through some ajax request. The problem is that one of the apache instances is blocked on 99%. I've tried with kill that_apache_pid, but I don't have the rights to do that.

Do you have any idea about how to stop that process, or I'll have to write to the administrator of that server to do it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are not the admin on that machine and can't `sudo` this, you will need to contact the admin. That's the whole point of this system: Not letting anyone kill any processes.